# Catalina USB not bootable

Tags: catalina, bootable-disk

I have followed all tutorials available to make bootable Catalina USB

I used following command to create bootable USB

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Install\ macOS\ Catalina
```

Command finishes successfully but when I restart with `Option` key, USB is not displayed and I cannot boot from it.

I tried to boot back using my boot drive and used `System Preferences -> Startup disk`, but when I try to choose USB volume then I got error message about

`The bless tool was unable to set the current boot disk`

I am unable to clean-install my OS because I simply cannot create bootable volume.

I also tried GUI `Install Disk Creator` but with same effect.

Any help?

Comment: Why not just use Internet Recovery?

Comment: I saved this option as a last resort, but eventually this was my only option.
Thanks for mentioning it though